# No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli

Tags: jdbc, informix

I have created a test program to connect to an Informix 7.31 TD6 database with Java and read the data from a table and I get the reference error (No suitable driver found for jdbc:informix-sqli)

The program throws this error only when in the connection url I write "localhost". If instead of "localhost" I write the name of the computer or the IP, no error appears but it stays processing and does nothing.

I have added all the Informix JDBC .jars to the project, so I think something must be wrong with the localhost, but I have it like this in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

so I think it is correct. The program is as follows:

```
     import java.sql.Connection;
     import java.sql.DriverManager;
     import java.sql.ResultSet;
     import java.sql.Statement;

     public class InformixConnection {
         public static void main(String[] args) {
         Connection connection = null;
         Statement statement = null;
         ResultSet resultSet = null;

         try {
             // Establish the connection to the Informix database
             String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:informix-sqli://compu-01:1526/tests:INFORMIXSERVER=ol_gechenique;user=informix;password=informix";
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl);

              // Create a SQL statement
              statement = connection.createStatement();

             // Execute a SQL query to read the data from the table
             String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Types_Srv";
         resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

             // Iterate over the results and display the data
             while (resultSet.next()) {
                 int id = resultSet.getInt("idtype_srv");
                 String name = resultSet.getString("description");

                 System.out.println("ID: " + id);
                 System.out.println("Name: " + name);
                 System.out.println("------------------");
             }
         } catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             // Close resources in reverse order
             try {
                 if (resultSet != null)
                     resultSet.close();
                 if (statement != null)
                     statement. close();
                 if (connection != null)
                     connection. close();
             } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
            }
         }
     }
```

I hope someone can give me a hand, because it's the first time it happens to me.

Greetings!

**EDIT:**

I thought that maybe the Informix was listening on another port than 1526, so I used the netstat command to check it, but from the results below, it is listening on the correct port and it shows the connections it has (SQL Editor ).

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> .\netstat -a | .\findstr "1526"                                                                   TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    COMPU-01:0             LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:49485         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:49621         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:54646         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:55383         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:56478         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:60546         ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.40.112:1526    compu-01:60800         ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Are you going to let your database server vote?  It's old enough to do so.  Version 7.31 has been out of service for a long time (more than a decade, I think), and was released even longer ago.  The first 7.31 versions were release before Y2K.  With that said, there's at least a chance that a modern Informix JDBC driver can connect even to 7.31, but it won't be a supported configuration.

Comment: If the program hangs can you get a stack trace of where it is hanging? You mention your program says processing but that message does not appear in the example code.  It's possible you just need to register the driver (really old drivers can't tell what version of the driver you have) might need to be manually registered using the DriverManager.registerDriver(IfxDriver.class) API

Comment: @BrianHughes `DriverManager.registerDriver` shouldn't be called from user code. From the very first JDBC specification, driver registration should happen when the driver class is loaded. Old drivers (before JDBC 4.0) may not support automatic loading using the ServiceLoader, but then a driver should be loaded with `Class.forName` so it registers itself, not by user code calling `registerDriver`.

Comment: Fair Point @MarkRotteveel. I recalled the prior drivers didn't register themselves, but Class.forName is probably the better way.